# Applying EF Core Migration for multiple databases dynamically (multitenancy)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, multi-tenant

The current .net core api I am working with connects to multiple databases based on the header metadata on each request.  I have the following scoped registration that connects the api to different database per request in my `Startup.cs`.

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>((serviceProvider, ctx) =>
        {
            var service = serviceProvider.GetService<ITenantMetaDataService>();
            var connectionString = service.GetConnectionString()

            ctx.UseSqlServer(connectionString); //<- connects to different tenant databases per request

        });
```

All tenant databases have similar schemas and single migration can be applied to all.

My question is how can I apply the migration at runtime for every connection. Most of the examples I see consider the migrations to apply only once when the application restarts. The scenario here is that a new tenant database might be added while the api is running and the api should be able to connect to the brand new db and apply the migration.

This scenario is not well suited for manual migration and I would like to do it programmatically. How do I add the migration so that it gets applied for every new db connection ? where in the application is a good place to put it as well ?
Should I apply the migration at the constructor of `ApiDbContext` ?

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: thanks for the pointer. The example assumes multiple providers and based on some criteria it connects to a specified one when the app starts. My case is a bit different, i have single provider which is Azure SQL DB but I want to connect to different sql dbs per equest and apply migration when I connect to a new database.

Comment: We created a custom tool, based on how Stack Overflow does things. We completely ditched EF migrations and just write our own SQL migrations and a tool to deploy them. https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/05/03/stack-overflow-how-we-do-deployment-2016-edition/#database-migrations

Comment: You have multiple providers, they are just the same type database instead of different types of databases.

Comment: jdWeng  thanks for the correction. but still trying to find a way to apply migration per request , any ideas  ?

Comment: @mason Thanks for the pointer. let me check

Comment: If you have list of tenants in application wide variable (singleton service), you can store database version as a field, when application loads for the first time. This service will also store a database target version. Provisioning a new tenant would add a new item to this list. This can in turn apply the migration once at the beginning when provisioning. And later,on each request you would query the singleton service for the tenant database version and target database version, if they mismatch apply the migration. Make sure to lock and unlock the database before and after applying migration.